# Android studio - Duplicate classes after copying project to another computer

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I started using android studio on a holiday with my laptop. I've gotten back home and I'd like to use my PC to continue with this project. I have a piece of software on both my laptop and PC called 'Sync Trayzor' and I use it to synchronise pictures, unity projects, .flp files, blender stuff, etc... between my home PC, laptop, school computer, phone, and some of my friends' devices.

I set it up to copy all files in the ~/AndroidStudioProjects folder:
[image]

between my laptop and desktop, and everything seemed to be working fine *until I tried to build the project*.

Whenever I try to build a project *using my desktop* that was copied from my laptop to my desktop (projects that were already on my desktop work fine) I get thousands of similar errors:

```
 Duplicate class com.google.common.xml.XmlEscapers found in modules jetified-guava-30.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
 Duplicate class com.google.common.xml.package-info found in modules jetified-guava-30.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
 Duplicate class com.google.thirdparty.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixPatterns found in modules jetified-guava-30.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
 Duplicate class com.google.thirdparty.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixType found in modules jetified-guava-30.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
 Duplicate class com.google.thirdparty.publicsuffix.TrieParser found in modules jetified-guava-30.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:30.1-android) and jetified-guava-jdk5-17.0 (com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0)
```

(These are just the last 5 out of many many many of them)

My guess is I'm copying all the built-in android studio classes to my desktop which already has them, however, I'm suuuuper new to android studio and I have no idea if there's a quick fix for this kind of thing.

Invalidating the cache and reloading the gradle did not help.

I'm happy to give more details if necessary, thanks!

Comment: probably irrelevant to your question, but you should consider getting a good gitignore file and just learning/using git, instead of some other software to do this for you

Comment: @a_local_nobody I'll look into that. It seems to work for others. Thanks